# Can the Silverlight XZing library automatically detect the type of barcode being scanned/captured?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, barcode, barcode-scanner

So I was curious, is it possible when using the Silverlight Xzing library to be able automatically detect the type of barcode that is being captured?

Or does it just rely on the user having some background knowledge on barcodes and choosing the BC type for the one they intend on scanning from a list box? (as shown [here](http://silverlightzxing.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3bd7fb2d5eb2#WP7_Barcode_Library/BarcodeTypeManager.cs))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at [Real-time video scan a barcode/QR code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephe/archive/2011/11/07/wp7-real-time-video-scan-a-barcode-qr-code-in-your-app-using-zxing-lib.aspx). As I understand  description, this code allows to automatically detect code type

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I'm after, looks pretty tough to embed into my application though